# What is error in the code for finding factorial in python by recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion, factorial

```
def fact(n):
    if n==1:
       return
    else:
        return (n * fact(n-1)) 
d=int(input("Enter the number"))
print(fact(d))
```

I am trying to learn recursive functions in python but I am getting an error in the above code

Comment: Your base case should return a value. Specifically the result of `fact(1)`

Comment: You must return value in initial case:

`if n==1:
       return 1`

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `n==1`, you have a bare return, which means you're implicitly returning `None`. From there on, errors ensue. Instead, you should explicitly return `1`:

```py
def fact(n):
    if n==1:
       return 1 # Here
    else:
        return (n * fact(n-1))
```

**Side note:**
Mathematically speaking, you should probably return 1 for `n==0`, not `n==1`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Factorial_of_zero for details.